# Fast way to multiply sparse matrices without enough memory

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

Iam using the Matrix package, and I need to perform the following operation

`sum(rowSums(triu(A% * %(D% * %t(A)),1)))`.

But I run out into cholmod error not enough memory because of A% * %(D% * %t(A)). Is there any efficient way to circumvent this?Thank you for reading.

P.S:D is a diagonal matrix, I have tried this

```
sumit<-vector(mode = "numeric",length = dim(A)[1]-1)
   sumit<-rep(0,dim(A)[1]-1)
   E<-D %*%t(A)
   for(i in 2:dim(A)[[1]]){
   for(j in 1:i-1){

      asumitar<-as.numeric(sumit[i] + as.numeric((A[i,] %*% E[,j])))
      if(length(asumitar)==0){asumitar<-0}
      sumit[i]<-asumitar

    }
  }
  n<-sum(sumit)
```

but it never finishes calculating.

Comment: http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/

Comment: Hi thank you, but using slam instead of Matrix is using more memory.